# Android Activity rotates after onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-activity, rotation, screen-orientation

I have an `Activity` which records videos from the front camera for the `Activity`. The orientation is locked to Portrait in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file via the following code:

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.SomeVideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="Video Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

This works fine if the user enters the screen for the first time. However, after leaving this activity and coming back to it, apparently landscape mode is re-enabled.

I managed to salvage the situation by forcing the orientation at via the following codeblock:

```
@Override
 protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

So I am just curious as to why this happens only on just this one activity. I have checked other activities for `onActivityResult` and they don't messed up the orientation settings at all.

**UPDATE**:

Actually this problem is solved by using `this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` as my sole intention is to lock the activity to portrait and disable landscape rotation. I just want to *understand* why rotation is re-enabled in `SomeVideoActivity` after it returns from another activity even though it is declared to have portrait orientation in `AndroidManifest`.

Comment: Remember: When you declare your activity to handle a configuration change, you are responsible for resetting any elements for which you provide alternatives. If you declare your activity to handle the orientation change and have images that should change between landscape and portrait, you must re-assign each resource to each element during 

[onConfigurationChanged().](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration))

Comment: @EmdadHossain, I have actually tried removing the `android:configChanges="orientation"` from the manifest previously but it made no difference. In fact, all my activities has the same settings in the manifest and this video recording activity is the one giving rotation issues after returning from another activity.

Comment: just to be sure 
**change**
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
**to**
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
let me know if any update..!!!

Comment: I did that as well. It did not work.

Comment: **change**
`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

**to**
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);

Comment: My intention is to disable landscape and lock screen to Portrait-Only. Wouldn't `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENS‌​OR);` make my screen rotate?

Comment: no, as you have defined the orientation in manifest file, but replacing the code does it work? give it a try.

Comment: @EmdadHossain, just tried it. Still rotates. I think I would just stick to my current implementation of `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORT‌​RAIT);` since it is the only way to stop it from rotating. I can only assume that the activity state has been wiped when it returns from the new activity.

Comment: OK, after a fair bit of study it shows camera surface view by default goes to landscape mode and see this  [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30684890/5689844) to change it to portrait along with other OK configurations

Comment: @EmdadHossain, Thanks for the help.

Comment: did it resolve the issue?

Comment: @EmdadHossain, no. Nothing seems to work except for the `setRequestOrientation` line. So I will be sticking to it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This post is a bit old, but i had the same problem (or similar). If the device was being held in landscape mode, when finishing the activity, the screen would rotate to landscape and then back to portrait (which is forced in the manifest).

This is the scenario

- Activity A starts Activity B for result.
- Activity B does its work and sets result.
- Activity B finishes itself.
- Activity A receives the result and finishes itself.

**setRequestedOrientation** didn't work for me. A small change that i did was instead of finishing the activity A right away after receiving the result, was to delay in 50ms by having a **postDelayed** call. This worked fine.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(this::finish, 50);
```

It is still a bit strange. It seems to be a Android bug when you finish more then one activity with no interval between them. Or just when you are using Camera API, maybe it is a race condition. Anyway, i'm just posting this here in case someone else faces the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add in manifest to your activity tag android:screenOrientation="portrait" this will prevent your activity being rotated.

Comment: It is already declared in the manifest. Issue here is that when I return from another activity, landscape mode is re-enabled and the activity is rotatable.